# binary search found index is incorrect

Tags: java, binary-search

I have this code to binary search.

```
public class BinarySearch {

private static int location;
private static int a = 14;
static int[] numbers = new int[]{3, 6, 7, 11, 14, 16, 20, 45, 68, 79};

public static int B_Search(int[] sortedArray, int key) {
    int lowB = 0;
    int upB = sortedArray.length;
    int mid;
    while (lowB < upB) {
        mid = (lowB + upB) / 2;

        if (key < sortedArray[mid]) {
            upB = mid - 1;
        } else if (key > sortedArray[mid]) {
            lowB = mid + 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BinarySearch bs = new BinarySearch();
   location= bs.B_Search(numbers, a);
   if(location != -1){
       System.out.println("Find , at index of: "+ location);
   }
   else{
       System.out.println("Not found!");
   }
}
}
```

output:

a=14 
 not Found!!

Why?

Comment: **Your sorted array is not sorted.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> output: a=68 not Found!! Why?

The binary search algorithm relies on the input being sorted to start with. It assumes that if it finds a value which is greater than the target one, that means it needs to look earlier in the input (and vice versa).

Your array isn't sorted:

```
static int[] numbers = new int[]{6, 3, 7, 19, 25, 8, 14, 68, 20, 48, 79};
```

Sort it to start with, and it should be fine.

Comment: You can only sort in `O(n log n)` with comparisons.

Comment: Sajjad - Unless this is an exercise in learning data structures and algorithms, why not leverage the libary? See Collections.sort and Collections.binarySearch

Comment: @Sajjad-: It's not clear what you goal is here. Are you trying to learn about binary search, or accomplish something in a real context? If it's the latter, you need to provide that context so we can help you appropriately. (And you don't need to implement `Arrays.binarySearch` yourself...)

Comment: @Sajjad-: Okay, so are you trying to learn about sorting or binary search? Concentrate on one at a time. If you're trying to learn about binary search, just sort the input array yourself... or call `Arrays.sort`, of course.

Comment: I know how sort a array , but i want a simple java arraySort method!

Comment: Are there this method like this?

Comment: As I said before: [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])). (And you should really learn to research things. Searching for "how do I sort an array in Java" gives plenty of good hits.)

Comment: @Sajjad- you should use your net skills for online search. Using *Java array sort* in google shows tutorials about how to use this method.